# How to make TabLayout scrollable in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

I have DrawerLayout  in Activity and from NavigationView different Fragments are opened.
one of the Fragments contains TabLayout.
when the page is scroll the Toolbar is scrolled up(becomes hidden),
while I need to hide TabLayout as well .there are a lot of sample the it is implemented via Activity ,while I have TabLayout in Fragment, need to scroll Toolbar and TabLayout scroll as in Play Store .
Here is the layouts activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/main_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

main_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".view.activity.MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/main_content" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

main_content.xml where I'm adding/replacing fragment

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>
```

this xml is one of the content of one of the Fragment's where it contains TabLayout which I want to be scrollable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please let me know if it was something that you were looking for.

Comment: <include layout="@layout/main_content" /> it should be after AppBarLayout

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious!

And unfortunately, You haven't tried anything or just trying to see the official examples or etc.

Anyways, It should be simple because you only need to remove the `TabLayout` **from the last `Layout`** and just replace it under the `Toolbar` and leave the rest there.

The last thing will be adding :

```
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
```

For making the `TabLayout` scrollable or hide in another words.

So ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.activity.MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/main_content" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFF00"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#0000FF"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: you mean TabLayout should be moved to main_screen,which a part of activity_main ,in such case if from navigation menu different fragments are opened and only one Fragment needs TabLayout I need to show/hide it for different fragments?

Comment: In your question you said; *one of the Fragments contains TabLayout. when the page is scroll the Toolbar is scrolled up(becomes hidden* so you only need to find that view and adding this TabLayout under the Toolbar. Please first check my answer and if it didn't work, Let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Simply just put app:tabMode="scrollable" inside the xml.

like that

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorGravity="stretch"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabIndicatorAnimationMode="elastic"
        app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/light_green"

        />
```